# Umschreiben von alter in neue Rechtschreibung

Tags: reformed-orthography, software

Ich muss einen größeren Text-Korpus aus den 70er-Jahren in die neue Rechtschreibung umschreiben und wollte gerne so viel wie möglich automatisieren und das, was sich ggf. nicht automatisieren lässt, möglichst systematisch angehen.

Wie könnte ich hier am besten vorgehen? Inwieweit könnte ich vorhandene Software einsetzen? Bezüglich allgemeiner Rechtschreib- und Grammatikfehler sind die Korrektur-Tools, die es so gibt, meines Wissens nach, wohl nicht besonders zuverlässig. Aber hier ist die Anforderung ja etwas anders. Die Texte sind ja "fehlerfrei". Nur eben in der alten Rechtschreibung.
Ich habe einen Artikel von 1999 gefunden, in dem eine damalige Software von Bertelsmann namens "Orthograph" besprochen wird, die von alter in neue Rechtschreibung umwandelt. Dort heißt es, dass das mit dieser Software ziemlich gut funktioniert. Leider habe ich den Eindruck, dass es schon lange keine Nachfrage mehr nach einer solchen Software gibt und entsprechend auch keine angeboten wird.

Bin für jegliche Tipps dankbar!

Comment: Eventuell wäre noch interessant, in welchem Format der Textkorpus vorliegt.

Comment: @HalvarF Also, PDF-Dokument, Word-Datei, LaTeX-Quelldatei, notfalls auch simple Text-Datei, wäre alles machbar. Kodierung: Unicode. Adobe Software verwende ich nicht (falls das relevant ist).

Comment: Wenn die Textmenge sehr groß ist, könnte es sich lohnen, sich selbst einen Konvertierer zu schreiben. Mit Natural-Language-Processing-tools wie spacy kann man die grammatische Struktur der Sätze aufschlüsseln. Ich weiß nur nicht genau, wie kompliziert die Regeländerungen sind - das meiste passiert doch auf der lexikalischen Ebene, oder?

Comment: Da die "neue" Rechtschreibung ja eigentlich auch schon langsam ziemlich alt ist, dürften solche Tools eher auf dem Stand von 1999 sein - Also über 20 Jahre alt. Davon würde ich nicht allzuviel erwarten. Ich würde das Zeug durch eine moderne Rechtschreibprüfung wie z.B. von MS Word rennen lassen und eine Sichtprüfung machen. Sooo umfangreich waren die Änderungen nicht, dass sich Automatisierung wirklich lohnen würde.

Comment: Naja, das ß trat schon recht häufig auf, und ich wüsste keine einfache (auf dem Level von Suchen-Ersetzen) Automatisierung von "ersetze alle ß nach einem kurzen Vokal mit ss".

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Ich erinnere mich an Änderungen bei der Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung, die vielleicht knifflig sein könnten. Bei der Zeichensetzung bin ich nicht sicher, ob es obligatorische Änderungen gab, das meiste war optional.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Es sind immerhin einige tausend Seiten. – Ja, ich wäre schon in der Lage, selbst eine Software zu schreiben. Allerdings, wie hier bereits von anderen angemerkt wurde, kann man (höchstwahrscheinlich) Vieles nicht anhand von Regeln umsetzen. Allein schon für ß/ss bräuchte man wohl Wortlisten, da man den kurz oder lang gesprochenen Vokal dem Wort nicht "ansehen" kann. Ich vermute, dass die Software-Lösungen, die es damals gab, auch viel mit Wortlisten arbeiten. Solche Listen zu erstellen, erscheint mir aber ziemlich aufwendig.

Comment: @keth-tex: Ich denke, es ist nicht so kompliziert, Wortlisten zu erstellen. Folgender Ansatz  erscheint mir recht effizient: Extrahiere alle Worte mit ß aus dem Text, lass sie dir einzeln anzeigen, und gib an, ob sie neu mit Doppel-S geschrieben werden. (Das Programm muss sich natürlich bereits erfolgte Etnscheidungen merken).  Da ist man in unter einer Stunde damit fertig, schätze ich.

Comment: Oder noch einfacher, es gibt so eine Wortliste schon: https://www.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/service/reform/aenderungen.pdf

Answer (score 2):

1999 gab es einen [Vergleichsartikel in der c't](https://www.heise.de/select/ct/archiv/1999/20/seite-172)

Unter anderem damals besprochen (grob absteigend nach Wertung):

- Corrigo 1.0 (CLT Sprachtechnologie Saarbrücken, Professioneller Anspruch, Preis damals 2500 €)
- DUDEN - Der Konverter (auch in einer erweiterten Version "DUDEN - Der Profi-Konverter")
- Bertelsmann Orthograf 3.0 (Koch Media)
- Rechtschreibung aktuell 3.0 (Kelly Data)

Eventuell kommt man da noch irgendwie heran. Perfekt waren die laut Artikel aber alle nicht.

Da man realistischerweise jede Änderung, die ein automatischer Konverter macht, sowieso nochmal überprüfen muss, ist vielleicht die einfachste Möglichkeit, die alten Texte je nach Format in eine heutige Textverabeitungssoftware mit aktueller Rechtschreibprüfung zu laden und sich mit den Tastenkürzeln für das Aussuchen/Annehmen/Ablehnen der vorgeschlagenen Änderungen vertraut zu machen.

Wenn die Texte nicht vertraulich sind, helfen möglicherweise auch aktuellere Online-Tools zur Rechtschreib- und Grammatikprüfung:

- https://www.deepl.com/write (Beta)
- https://languagetool.org/de
- https://www.scribbr.de/rechtschreibpruefung/
- https://mentor.duden.de/

Zum Teil muss man da allerdings ein Abo abschließen und hat selbst dann nur eine begrenzte Textlänge im Monat. Zum Teil gibt es APIs oder Plugins für Textprogramme, Editoren und Browser.

Comment: Ich denke auch, dass eine moderne Rechtschreib/ Grammatikkorrektur hilfreich ist, aber ich glaube nicht alle Konstruktionen die von alter in neue Rechtschreibung umgewandelt werden sollten, würden in einer Rechtschreibkorrektur als Fehler erkannt werden.